# Escape string characters

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string as given below:

```
"\"funlolx.com, Likesgag.com (269556)\",3,0,0.000000000000000000"
```

I want the string as below so that I can split it by `","`,

```
"funlolx.com Likesgag.com (269556),3,0,0.000000000000000000"
```

so the final output I get would be like:

```
["funlolx.com Likesgag.com (269556)", "3", "0", "0.000000000000000000"]
```

Comment: This looks like CSV, why don't you simply parse it as such?

Comment: No, in CSV we done it right. but this string is coming in JSON.

Comment: Okay, then parse it as JSON? But it doesn't look like JSON, it's missing the `[` and `]` delimiters. It really looks like CSV, and it can be parsed perfectly fine as CSV.

Comment: @JörgWMittag this case is not here we have to do lots of calculation in JSON then we get this string. So parsing is not right thing. We have to try different solution.

Comment: But why not parse it? You have benchmarked it and it is too slow? We can't give you anything better than parsing this as CSV if we don't know specifically why you don't wont to use this solution, because using CSV parser on string you get from JSON file is completely fine (though unsual) thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"\"funlolx.com, Likesgag.com (269556)\",3,0,0.000000000000000000"
.gsub(/"[^"]+"/){|s| s.delete('",')}
# => "funlolx.com Likesgag.com (269556),3,0,0.000000000000000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspiciously like CSV to me:

```
require 'csv'
table = CSV.parse('"funlolx.com, Likesgag.com (269556)",3,0,0.000000000000000000')
# => [["funlolx.com, Likesgag.com (269556)", "3", "0", "0.000000000000000000"]]
```

Note: CSV expects to get a table, i.e. an array of arrays. In this case, there is only one row in the table, so you want to get the first one:

```
table.first
# => ["funlolx.com, Likesgag.com (269556)", "3", "0", "0.000000000000000000"]
```

If you *really* must get rid of the comma, then you can use all of Ruby's standard string operations:

```
table.first.map {|s| s.delete(',') }
# => ["funlolx.com Likesgag.com (269556)", "3", "0", "0.000000000000000000"]
```